# A chord of length $6$ subtends an $80^\circ$ central angle in a circle. Can we calculate the distance from center to chord without trigonometry?

Tags: triangles, circles

I know that the following can be answered easily using trigonometric ratios, but is there any way to go about it **without relying on trigonometry**? (The book from which the problem was taken doesn't cover trig before this point.)

$O$ is the centre of a circle, and $PQ$ and $RS$ are two equal length chords in it. Points $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of the two chords $PQ$ and $RS$ respectively. The length of $PQ$ is given as $6$cm and the measure of the angle $\angle POQ$ (where $O$ is the vertex) is given as $80^\circ$ degrees. A diagram of this is in the snapshot I've attached. The question is, how do you calculate the length $|OM|$?

[image: Diagram of the circle]

Comment: What is the relevance of the RS chord? And what's the problem with trigonometry?

Comment: Well, the length of $OM$ (in centimeters) is $3\cot 40^\circ$. Computing this cotangent requires solving a degree 3 equation, because you need to trisect the angle of $120^\circ$.

Comment: @rafa11111 it's just that the book from which I took this problem doesn't cover trigonometry before this point. I was precocious so I was wondering whether there were any other way to approach this without relying on trigonometry.

Comment: @rafa11111 $RS$ doesn't appear to be of much significance to my knowledge. I just wanted to lay out all the info given in the book, in case something that I couldn't see turn out to be hugely relevant for the solution.

Comment: @egreg According to Wolfram, $3 \cot 40^\circ$ has the minimal polynomial $3x^6  -26x^4 + 33x^2 - 1$.

Comment: @ConnorHarris Yes, but this reduces to a degree 3 equation, doesn't it?

Comment: @egreg Correction! I meant to say that the minimal polynomial of $\cot 40^\circ$ (not $3 \cot 40^\circ$) is $3x^3 - 27x^2 + 33x - 1$. There's a surprisingly acceptable closed form $$\cot 40^\circ = \sqrt{ 3 - \frac{2k}{3} - \frac{8}{k} }$$ where $k$ is the fourth-quadrant cube root of $-36 + 12i \sqrt{3}$, but I don't see any natural geometric argument that wold get this result for us.

Comment: OP, is this really the entire problem in the book?

Comment: @ConnorHarris  Thanks for your replies!

Comment: @egreg Thanks for your replies!

Comment: I'm terribly sorry about this late reply! So the consensus is that this is not doable without relying on trigonometry right? And @ConnorHarris yes, this is all the info that was given. I've only taken a snapshot of the diagram. But I've included all the other details - including those that were in the problem itself, and others that I figured out in the process of going through this problem - in the description that precedes the diagram.

Comment: And thanks goes to @Blue for that bit of editing which has considerably improved the presentation :)

Comment: Final correction, in case anyone comes across this question in the future: I got the minimal polynomial of $\cot 40^\circ$ wrong again. It's $3x^6 - 27x^4 + 33x^2 - 1$ (i.e., replace $x$ with $x^2$ in the one I gave before).

Comment: @egreg One final question. Why not use $\tan 40^0$ instead of $\cot 40^0$ ?

Comment: @Indula That's the same, because it's the reciprocal. Say that $\cot40^\circ$ satisfies the irreducible polynomial $x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ (so $c\ne0$). Then $\tan40^\circ$ satisfies $cx^3+bx^2+ax+1$.

Comment: @egreg Oh okay! I'm sorry I'm bit of a novice to this. Haven't really studied the trigonometric functions properly to handle the polynomials you guys were talking about. Is the trigonometric ratio of $\tan 40^0$ sufficient for the purpose of calculating the length of $OM$ ?

Comment: @Indula what represents the red segment above the circle?

Comment: @user376343 I'm sorry about the delay. That red line is from a diagram immediately above this circle. Didn't realise until now that the screen shot captured that!